# Load on demand for dynamic report

Tags: performance, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I had a huge CSV file which is of 2GB for which I would like to generate a dynamic report. Is there any possibility to load only 1st few MB of data into that report and on scrolling the report to next page then load next few MB of data and so on... for good performance to avoid crashes data to be visualized is huge?

Answer (score 0):

Our [JRCsvDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRCsvDataSource.html) implementation (assuming this is the one you want to use) does not consume memory while reading CSV data from the file or input stream, as it does not hold to any values and just parses data row by row. But if the data amount is huge, then the report output itself will be huge, in which case you need to use a report [virtualizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/virtualizer/index.html#virtualizer) during report filling and then viewing/exporting.